# Nginx: How to close connections that have been open for over an hour?

Tags: networking, nginx, cron

I am using an Nginx server with Debian 11 to offer download resources.

I need to reset client connections that have been open for over an hour.

Currently, I restart the Nginx service via a cron job every hour. This method is too aggressive and closes client connections that have been open for less than an hour.

I'm looking for a solution to gracefully close connections that have been open for over an hour without affecting other open connections.

Is there any Nginx configuration to give an expiration date/time to open connections so that they close immediately after they expire?

Comment: Are you talking about a connection timeout or an active connection that, after 1 hour, just dies. I mean [timeouts in Nginx](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-nginx/) are pretty standard.

Comment: No, I want to close all active connections after one hour without impacting other client connections. Thank